# How might I plot multiple lines (same data, different styles) with a single plotting command in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

In my example, I want to plot a "highlighting" line (a heavy black line with a narrower yellow line over it to create a black outline) behind the actual data (the blue 'Pitch Angle' line in my example).

[image: Example of the effect I want, created with multiple plot commands.]

My function `highlight` does this for elements in pandas Series `x` where `h` is `True` and also finally plots `x`.  `highlight` returns unique identifiers for the highlighting lines created and the actual line styles used to allow the legend entries to be edited to produce what you see in the image, but as far as I can tell that has to be done after all plot commands, i.e. outside of `highlight`, assuming other things will be added to the Axes e.g. the 'Fine pitch' and '10 degrees' lines in my example.

```
def highlight(x, h, hlw=8, hc='#FFFBCC', hll='Highlighted', **kwargs):

    """
    Plot data in Series x, highlighting the elements correponding to True in h.
    """

    # For passing to extra the highlighter lines, drop any passed kwargs which
    # would clobber their appearance.  Keep a copy of the full set for the data.
    # The extra lines are plotted first so they appear underneath the actual
    # data.
    fullkwargs = kwargs.copy()
    for k in ['lw', 'linewidth', 'linestyle', 'ls', 'color', 'c', 'label']:
        kwargs.pop(k, None)

    # Generate a probably unique ID so that the legend entries of these lines
    # can be identified by the caller.
    import random
    gid = random.random()

    # Plot the highlighting lines.  First, plot a heavier black line to provide
    # a clear outline to the bright highlighted region.
    x.where(h).plot(lw=hlw+2, c='k', label='_dont_put_me_in_legend', **kwargs)
    # Plot the bright highlighter line on top of that.  Give this line an id.
    x.where(h).plot(lw=hlw, c=hc, label=hll, gid=gid, **kwargs)

    # Plot the actual data.
    a = x.plot(**fullkwargs)

    # Generate the custom legend entry artists.
    import matplotlib.lines as mlines
    l1 = mlines.Line2D([], [], lw=hlw+2, c='k')
    l2 = mlines.Line2D([], [], lw=hlw, c=hc)

    # Return the unique identifier of this call, and the tuple of line styles to
    # go to HandlerTuple (see
    # http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handlers).  This
    # makes it possible to update all "highlighter" legend entries with the
    # correct color-on-black visual style produced here.
    return {gid: (l1, l2)}
```

I manage to generate an accurate legend entry for the highlighting by making use of [HandlerTuple](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handlers) when calling plt.legend() by looping over all legend entries and replacing legend keys where `gid` is one of the values returned by `highlight`.

```
handles,labels = a.get_legend_handles_labels()
newhandles = []

for h in handles:

    if h.get_gid() in hi:

        newhandles.append(hi[h.get_gid()])

    else:

        newhandles.append(h)

a.legend(newhandles, labels)
```

Is there a way in matplotlib to define a "compound" line style such that one plot command produces the desired appearance and has only one legend entry?